# Editing messy SAQL - adding bindings

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

I have an interesting challenge on my hands. The solution I'm implementing required editing the SAQL in order to implement some subtotaling that isn't supported by the WYSIWYG...

Having done that, I now need to add the bindings. But the SAQL query itself is now an utter disaster - instead of being well-formed JSON it's basically a big spew of characters and newlines.

It works, but adding the bindings to that mess seems impossible. Has anybody dealt with this?